# Airflow Map-Reduce Operator

Tags: oozie, airflow

I am looking for an airflow map reduce operator. I use OOZIE map reduce action now, and trying to convert to Airflow. I have looked under
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/index.html, and
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html

could not find any map reduce operator. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a generic "HadoopMR" Operator.

If you are running (by chance) your Hadoop Claster using DataProc - you have the operator to submit a job there:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocSubmitHadoopJobOperator

But if you need to run it in your on-premise Hadoop Cluster, then you likely need to run some BashOperator with Hadoop command line tools.